# Enzyme testing - ReferenceError event is not defined

Tags: javascript, enzyme

I have a simple React component as below:

```
class AutoComplete extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {userName: ""};
}

_onChange(event) {
    this.setState({userName: event.target.value});
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className="autoCompleteContainer" >
            <input id="searchUsers" ref="searchUsers" onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
                   placeholder="Enter string" value={this.state.userName} />
            <div className="searchIcon fa fa-search" ></div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

I have written an enzyme test for the same:

```
describe("Testing chart", () => {
let spyOnChange = sinon.spy(Autocomplete.prototype, "_onChange");
let wrapper = mount(<Autocomplete/>);
it("should show correct list when typed something", () => {
    wrapper.update();
    wrapper.find("#searchUsers").simulate("change", {target: {value: "us"}});
    //expect(spyOnChange.called).toEqual(true);
});
});
```

When I run the test, I get the error: `ReferenceError: event is not defined`. What am I doing wrong here? I have a similar test on another React component that has a select tag and it works fine there. What seems to be wrong here?

I'm using Mocha as the test runner.

Thanks!

Comment: You do have many typos. Autocomplete should be AutoComplete as thats the name of ur class. Also, are you using chai? then for chai, the syntax is to.Equal.true. The syntax which u have used to.Equal(true) is of jasmine.

Comment: No, I did `import Autocomplete from <path>` so it's correct. And I'm using mocha and expect libraries and the syntax is also correct :)